# SELECT specific string pattern from mysql table

Tags: mysql, select

this is what I know

```sql
SELECT domain FROM domain_table GROUP BY domain
```

Here is a possible result

```
www.domain.com, domain.com, sub.domain.com, domain.co/a-page
```

Is it possible to apply regex (or a hack) to the above select statement so that i will get `domain.co` instead of `domain.co/a-page`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly you can try

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(domain, '/', 1) domain
  FROM domain_table
 GROUP BY SUBSTRING_INDEX(domain, '/', 1)
```

Here is a [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=11143ba2bf0c81492649912d36acb5a0) demo

Output:

```
domain
--------------
domain.co
domain.com
sub.domain.com
www.domain.com
--------------
```

Comment: i was looking for an php side solution for OP but i'm still faberglasted by how much SQL can do for you.